# Will Google index and assign keyword value to content in closed accordion sections?

Tags: seo, optimization

I currently have an accordion with my content in on my pages. I know Google is starting to crawl websites in mobile and hidden content shouldn't be an issue at the moment but I'm mixing it up a little and wondering if Google will still read the content and give it SEO value e.g.

- Top Accordion - Open
- Rest of Accordion - Collapsed

Should all the accordion be open for now?

Comment: You can assure the indexing of those sections by [submitting your sitemap to Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its really up to you and you don't need to worry about leaving the accordion open or closed.

Let's say that the content is hidden to the user, accordions uses JavaScript to hide or show the content, as long as the javascript is accessible to Googlebot you won't have any issue with your SEO, because [Google can access Javascript](https://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157) code and understand that you are using it to hide the content and will be able to also parse or read the hidden content from the source code.

You need to check that your website robots.txt file is not blocking Google to understand that the hidden content is temporary. Go to **yourdomain.com/robots.txt** and make sure no folder or file containing the Accordion Javascript code is blocked like

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /folder/accordion/javascript
or
Disallow: /javascript
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes Google and other search engines will index content in "accordions", "drawers", or other types of collapsible UI element. The decision to keep the accordion open or not should be a design decision driven by user experience.